# FCC / CE requirements for adapter pcb?

Tags: testing, fcc, certification, ce, compliance

A product consisting (electronically) just of a PCB with a male USB-C one one side, 5mm of traces and a female USB-C on the other end. No other components at all. To be used as consumer device.

How much FCC and CE testing would really be required, if any?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sell the thing in Europe, you need to affix CE. For CE, the intended use determines what [**directives**](https://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/ce-marking/manufacturers_en) you need to comply to.
This is probably limited to:

- Electromagnetic compatibility
- Restriction of Hazardous Substances in Electrical and Electronic Equipment

You **can** use harmonised standards to make very plausible your product is satisfying the EMC directive, and while it is one of the best ways to do it, you don't **have** to.

I **think** when you connect the shields of the USB such that it forms a cage of Faraday, you can make use of article 2 (d) of the [EMC directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1461936830934&uri=CELEX:32014L0030)

> equipment the inherent nature of the physical characteristics of which is such that:
>
> (i) it is incapable of generating or contributing to electromagnetic emissions which exceed a level allowing radio and telecommunication equipment and other equipment to operate as intended; and
>
> (ii) it operates without unacceptable degradation in the presence of the electromagnetic disturbance normally consequent upon its intended use;

The generating of EM emmisionis obviously not present. The contribution and susceptibility to EM emmision is made plausible by the Faraday cage.